# How to draw a perpendicular line from each point of a training set to surface plane in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-regression, training-data

I'm using matplotlib. I have a following linear regression model with a surface plane and training data set.

I need to draw orthogonal distance from each data point to the surface plane that would look similar to this:
[image]

Here is the code snippet that I have:

```
nx, ny = (100, 100)

x1 = np.linspace(-3, 10.0, nx)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 15.0, ny)

x_plane, y_plane = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)

XY = np.stack((x_plane.ravel(), y_plane.ravel()),axis =1)

z_plane = np.array([normal_equation(x,y) for x,y in XY]).reshape(x_plane.shape)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax  = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

ax.scatter(X2, X1, Y, color='r')
ax.plot_surface(x_plane, y_plane, z_plane, color='b', alpha=0.4)
ax.set_xlabel('x1')
ax.set_ylabel('x2')
ax.set_zlabel('y')
ax.set_zlim(-10, 5)
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Dasha, apologies if you had trouble with my answer. I found some errors after I posted it and have updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some simple mathematical facts we can use to solve this problem:

- The cross product of two vectors on the plane is a vector perpendicular to the plane.
- The dot product of two vectors measures the distance that each vector travels along the same direction as the other vector.

First, we can find a vector perpendicular to the plane using the following code:

```py
perpendicular = np.cross(
  (0, 1, normal_equation(0, 1) - normal_equation(0, 0)),
  (1, 0, normal_equation(1, 0) - normal_equation(0, 0))
)
normal = perpendicular / np.linalg.norm(perpendicular)
```

(Note: we assumed here that the plane is not vertical which it shouldn't be in linear regression)

Second, we need to trace back each point along this normal vector back to the plane.

```py
plane_point = np.array([0, 0, normal_equation(0, 0)])
dot_prods = [
  np.dot(np.array(u) - plane_point, normal)
  for u in zip(X2, X1, Y)
]
closest_points = [
  np.array([X2[i], X1[i], Y[i]]) - normal * dot_prods[i]
  for i in range(len(Y))
]
```

Finally, we can draw connections between each of these points.

```py
for i in range(len(Y)):
  ax.plot(
    [closest_points[i][0], X2[i]],
    [closest_points[i][1], X1[i]],
    [closest_points[i][2], Y[i]],
    'k-'
)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a coherent explanation. But `closest_points[i][0]` gives me an array of 3 values instead of a coordinate along one axes?

Comment: So I tried to modify this part of your code:
`closest_points = [
  np.array([X2[i], X1[i], Y[I]]).reshape(3) - normal * dot_prods[i]
  for i in range(len(Y))
]` but it draw me funny lines not perpendicular to the plane at all. I guess there is something wrong with finding the closest points:( any suggestions? thanks a lot @Matthew Miller

Comment: @DashaRee, I assumed that `X1`, `X2`, and `Y` were either lists or single-dimensional arrays. If they aren't, then that could forseeably not work well with my code. Could you report the shapes of these? As for the algorithm not producing the correct results, you may want to check the order of `X1` and `X2` throughout your code. This could easily mess up the algorithm. I've written a small example of the algorithm using these assumptions. See this: https://repl.it/@MatthewMiller4/Perpendicular-Lines#main.py

Comment: yes, sorry `X1`, `X2`, `Y` were `(N, 1)` shape. I just reshaped them into a single-dimensional array and got it working! Thank you so so much!